# My website "Current location" function does now work on android devices

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, cross-platform, android-browser

Here is the function I call on link click, which works fine on iPhone and in PC/Apple devices browsers, but do not work in any of Android devices browsers:

```
  function currentLocation() {

      // Initialize the Google Maps API v3

      var MyMarker = null;

      function autoUpdate() {

      if (navigator.geolocation) {    
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var newPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
                                                position.coords.longitude);

          if (MyMarker) {
            // Marker already created - Move it
            MyMarker.setPosition(newPoint);
          }
          else {
            // Marker does not exist - Create it
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: newPoint,
              map: map
            });
          }

          // Center the map on the new position
          map.setCenter(newPoint);
        });

        } // End if

        // Call the autoUpdate() function every 5 seconds
        setTimeout(autoUpdate, 5000);
      }

      autoUpdate();

  }
```

Once I visit the page which contains this script and press the button to show my current location device does ask me to let the location to be shared, but then nothing happens. There is no errors in console.

Please advice on how to make this working for android based devices.

Comment: http://html5demos.com/geo - this link does not work on my android phone either! Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested on multiple phones?

You may have to enable location services: https://support.google.com/coordinate/answer/2569281?hl=en

Comment: yes, my location services are enabled. I have tested on Acer s500 and Samsung Galaxy tablet

Comment: http://html5demos.com/geo - this link does not work on my android phone either! Any ideas why???